# PHP Wordpress Form Action is not a file type, where is it going?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I had a site coded in wordpress, and now I'm taking over the code (a newbie).

The line in question:

`<form id="analyse_form" action="./resume-analysis" method="post">`

The problem is, the action, where are the form results going? I don't see a resume-analysis file obviously (it's not a php file), so what is it, and where should I be able to see this.

TIA.

Comment: I would really recommend that you take a good look at htaccess tutorial before trying to edit wordpress code

Comment: There's nothing that says an URL has to resolve to an actual file, and in Wordpress it often doesn't.

Comment: Find the rule in htaccess or just find this resume-analysis in htaccess

Comment: We need far more context in order to answer this.  WHERE (in the code) is that line you are showing? HOW is the action being set? IF you browse to `resume-analysis`, what do you see? IF it's a WordPress page, then you'd need to know more about what's happening on that page.  Is there a shortcode? Widget? Something else that is watching for this form post and processing it?

Comment: Here is my htaccess file:

`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
`

Comment: It's hard to help if you don't answer all of the questions I asked.

Comment: Here is some more details, hopefully it helps.
The action is from a form on the homepage, I don't see a mysite.com/resume-analysis although this is the page that it navigates too once the form button is pressed. There is shortcode used to bring the form onto the homepage.  Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resume-analysis was a page in wordpress, and then from there I saw some short code, so that's where the logic is stored for the form.

Appreciate the replies - and sorry for my lack of understanding, i'm a really noob here.

Answer (score 0):

`/resume-analysis` is most likely being re-written to another file (probably `index.php` if it's Wordpress). In Wordpress pretty much all URLs are 're-written' to index.php (i.e all URLs are loaded via index.php).

If it's using a plugin the file could be in the plugins folder, but it could be buried deep within.

Comment: The main logic is utilized with a plugin, but is the `/resume-analyis` a folder, a file, what could this be.

I would suspect a php file like 'resume-analyis.php' but I don't see this.

Any context would be great.

Comment: Any help is appreciated, i'm desperate here!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have this rule inside your .htaccess (maybe you're not using apache?) Look into your nginx / apache / litespeed (or whatever server) configuration for your virtual host and somewhere, there should be a rewrite for `/resume-analysis`.

Do you have a .htaccess file and are you using apache?

Comment: WordPress is resolving that rule automatically.  The htaccess is just a feeder for WP, it won't have `resume-analysis` in it.

Comment: We never know for sure unless we check, but indeed, most rewrites on wordpress go to index.php.

Comment: Nothing in htaccess, i've pasted my htaccess file above.